# Setting "visual bell" in iterm on OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

Does anyone know how to set the audible bell to a visual bell in iterm? I've looked around a bit with no luck. I'm on OSX `10.6.3` and iterm Build `0.10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just implemented the feature last week in iTerm2! It will be in the next release, or you can try building from head if you want it right away. You can get source and binaries here: http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/

Answer (score 0):

I remember an [old MacWorld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/55182/2007/02/alertsounds.html) where they discussed making a custom .aif file to be used as a visual alarm. Excerpt:

> It turns out that the Sound System Preferences panel doesn’t like it if you tell it to use an invalid sound file. And it lets you know its displeasure by… you guessed it… flashing the screen! So all you need to do is create an invalid sound file, which you can easily do in Text Edit. Open a new blank document, type a space, and save it as Screen Flash.aif, or whatever name you want—just make sure you end it in .aif.

Now that's for Sound System Preferences, so I'm not sure if it's global. That is, I'm not sure if iTerm would react the same way to an invalid .aif file.