# setting visual bell to flash in iTerm

Tags: macos, ssh, display, iterm, bell

I am using iTerm on OSX (leopard) to ssh to a linux machine. I run screen on the dev machine to save my work between sessions. I am not a big fan of audio bell and I don't like screen's default 'Wuff Wuff' bell (or any other little message shown at bottom of the page). What I like though is to have flash (foreground and blackground colors swapped for a fraction of a second) as my visual bell. I used to use PuTTY and it is as simple as ticking a checkbox but I can't find such an option in iTerm. My question is how can I set my visual bell to flash?

The ideal answer would work with iTerm on local computer, iTerm sshed to a linux server, and  iTerm sshed to a linux server and ran screen.

Answer (score 9):

In newer versions (I'm in 2.0.0.20141103 on OS X Yosemite), it looks like they moved the setting to Profiles → Terminal → (Default profile) → Terminal. This doesn't switch the foreground and background colors like you're asking for, but it does display a big visual bell in the middle of the terminal. See this image of the settings page:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the simplest things are the most tricky.

1. Go to the preferences of iTerm.
2. Go to the advanced section of your scheme (or those you use).
3. Set visual bell and unset audio bell
   [image]
   That should work.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @George the required behaviour can be achieved by following the previous answers first by setting the bell in the Preferences:

[image: Profiles pane]

And then go to the Advanced settings and configure the following as well:

[image: Advanced pane]

Answer (score 2):

See my answer in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/143737/setting-visual-bell-in-iterm-on-osx): the code change is already checked in and iTerm2 will have it in the next release.